# Sqlite Android, 2 apps acessando um banco de dados

Tags: java, android

Como faço para que 2 aplicações utilizem o mesmo banco de dados?
Se crio o banco em um app o outro não acessa esse banco, então como fazer esse 2º app acessar esse mesmo banco?

Comment: Veja [Provedores de conteúdo(Content providers)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi bem sua pergunta, mas, se você criou o banco num smartphone, outro provavelmente não terá acesso. O que deve fazer nesse caso é criar um serviço na web com um banco na nuvem onde os apps independente de em que smartphone esteja, possa acessar. Entende?
Se é necessário ter bancos de dados nos smartphones, certifique-se se é necessário sincronizar com o banco na nuvem, via serviço (API, Web servisse, etc).

Comment: Mas eu teria que fazer um banco nuvem se quisesse acessar um banco em 1 smartphone porém em duas aplicações? Exemplo : uma aplicação de registro de dados e outra com a consulta desses dados

Comment: O mesmo banco e acessado. Porém via api.